# Send 30 Day Email Reminder in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to send an email 30 days before an individual is set to arrive at my company.

I have a list with individuals set to arrive to my company in it.  The date the individual is set to arrive is in a column "Estimated Date of Arrival".

I have tried setting up the workflow several different ways using several responses to similar quesitons, but none seem to resolve my issue.

[image]

My expected outcome is for an email to be sent 30 days before an individual is set to arrive (Estimated Date of Arrival).

Answer (score 0):

From you description, my understanding is that you want to send an email 30 days before the column "Estimated Date of Arrival" using workflow.

You don't have to use the loop step in your workflow, just pause until the date, then send an email. Like this:
[image]